# Site original não aceita CSS que em localhost está funcionando

Tags: html, css, wordpress, git, versionamento

Uso o **GIT** para o versionamento do projeto em desenvolvimento. 
Tenho um formulário feito com o *Contact Form 7* e para mudar o padrão dele, alterei algumas classes com [css](/questions/tagged/css). Na versão local deu certo. Porém ao comitar para o server, o CSS não é aceitado, sendo que no arquivo `style.css` do server está igual ao `style.css` local.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Verifiquei que todos os [css](/questions/tagged/css) agora não estão indo pro server quando é *commitado*. Detalhe que somente os atributos adicionados não estão funcionando. Sendo que o caminho do `<head></head>` está Ok, senão nada funcionava.

Comment: Você limpou o cache do navegador?

Comment: O seu arquivo `style.css` não está apontando para o endereço correto quando é feito o deploy. Poderias, por favor, postar o `<head></head>` do seu seu site?

Answer (score 1):

A causa mais provável deve ser o caminho que era usado no localhost seja diferente no de produção.

Usando o firefox abra o debug (tecla de atalho F12, não é o firebug)

> Console > Desmarque todos, e deixe somente o `Net`

depois disso de um reload na sua página,

volte para o console, lá vai mostrar o caminho (errado) do css

Comment: provavelmente ele utilizou caminho manual e não variavel de home_url ou site_url do wp